# why do I get the error message "'str' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index 0'" here

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a dataframe with a column of phone numbers which I'd like to map to country (as a new column "phone_country"), based on their country code. I realise there's probably a Python library to do this, but right now I'd like to understand why I get the error message
"'str' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index 0'"

I did try to ensure that the phone_number column was a string
`df['phone_number'] = df['phone_number'].apply(str)`

```
def phone_country(df):
    if df['phone_number'].str[:1] == '7': 
        value = 'RUS'
    elif (df['phone_number'].str[:2] == '34'): 
        value = 'ESP'
    elif (df['phone_number'].str[:2] == '39'): 
        value = 'ITA'
    elif (df['phone_number'].str[:3] == '212'): 
        value = 'MAR'
    else:
        value = 'Other'
    return value

df['phone_country'] = df.apply(phone_country, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `df.apply(phone_country, axis=1)`, it will run `phone_country` once for each row of `df`.  The argument `df` you receive in the function is *not* a `DataFrame`, but rather a `Series` representing the row.

Therefore `df['phone_number']` will pull out a single element of type `str` from that row, rather than operating on the whole column as `.str` would do.

You can either change your function to do things like:

```
if df['phone_number'][:1] == '7':
```

OR you can use a vectorized conditional, which is a bit uglier but will be much more performant:

```
df['phone_country'] = np.where(df['phone_number'].str[:1] == '7', 'RUS',
                      np.where(df['phone_number'].str[:2] == '34', 'ESP',
                      np.where(df['phone_number'].str[:2] == '39', 'ITA',
                      np.where(df['phone_number'].str[:3] == '212', 'MAR', 
                      'Other'))))
```